# Replace oven timer with switch

Tags: wiring, oven

I have a Moulinex Series O35 convection oven. The timer has stopped working, and after taking it apart, I found that the timer was broken (one of the connections had broken off).

I'm wondering if I can simply replace the timer with a standard switch from the hardware store.

Is it possible and safe just to put a switch where the timer was and replace the timer's connections with the switch's?

The timer's serial number is e210866

Comment: With a timer, if you forget, the timer will turn off.  With a simple switch, it will not turn off.

Comment: You don't show a picture or explain exactly how it is broken, but might be possible to repair/fix.  If lucky, might also be an inexpensive part to replace.

Comment: Have you searched the internet for a direct replacement part? That should be the first step before even considering cobbling something together that may or may not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Theoretically you could. But keep in mind that:

- The switch needs to be capable of switching the full current & voltage. A quick search finds mixed answers - French manufacturer, all prices of anything (mostly used) in Euros, which would imply ~ 240V/50Hz. On the other hand, searching for the switch finds markings of 120V or 125V, 15A, 60 Hz. So not clear *exactly* what you've got, but pretty sure the timer or switch needs to be rated to handle the full power requirements of the oven.
- A typical switch isn't going to be a direct (same form factor) replacement, so insulation of wires/connectors, making sure nothing can fall in/around the switch into the oven controls, etc. is critical for safety.
- As noted in a comment, if you use an ordinary switch then there is the "got on a call and forgot to turn off the oven" followed by "what's that smell?" followed by "smoke alarm" is a real possibility.

So conceptually, "yes", but practically, "no".

Comment: Given that a switch might not be the best option after all, is there something more reasonable that I could find at a local hardware store, or will I have to resort to ordering the same timer part online?

Comment: I don't know that oven, but usually that spot needs heat resistant components, a standard timer will not. You could permanently connect the wires, bypassing the timer, and then the oven is manually turned on and off.

Comment: The e210866 timer is available for $13 from a [well-known internet marketplace](https://www.ebay.com/itm/154591837244?hash=item23fe643c3c:g:ewwAAOSwWWdeIxJs).

Answer (score 3):

If you do not replace the timer-switch with the same timer-switch you will have made modifications to the oven that void its safety listing, whatever that may be for your locality.

That will shift any liability from a failure of the oven that causes a house fire or the like from the manufacturer to you. It will also provide your insurer with an excuse not to pay a claim.